# Optimizing UIColor Animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, uicolor

I'm trying like hell to make this GIF I have to show on an iPhone app I'm building. I'm at the point now where I'm profiling the app, and I realized that I was continuously allocated a `UIColor` and it was using virtually all of the phone's CPU.

I've been trying like hell all morning to optimize this function that I use to create and run the animation. If anyone has some insight, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I'm just trying to pull that UIColor out of the for statement, but maybe someone out there will see that I can do this a better way.

```
- (void)doBackgroundColorAnimation
{
     static NSInteger i = 0;
     int count = 34;
     NSMutableArray *colors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
     for (int i=1; i<=34; i++) {
     NSString *strImgName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"layer%d.png", i];
     UIColor *image = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:strImgName]];
     if (image) {
     [colors addObject:image];
     }
     }

     if (i >= [colors count]) {
     i = 1;
     }
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05f
     animations:^{
     self.animationView.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     ++i;
     [self doBackgroundColorAnimation];
     }];
}
```

**EDIT: Request to post code**

```
NSMutableArray *colors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
static NSString *strImgName;
UIColor *image = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:strImgName]];
for (int i=1; i<=34; i++) {
strImgName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"layer%d.png", i];
if (image) {
[colors addObject:image];
}
}
```

That returns -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array

Comment: Obvious solution: why not move the allocation/initialization of colors outside the loop?

Comment: Because if I did, I can't set the pattern Image like I need to in order to show the GIF. But that should be obvious to you...

Comment: "I can't set the pattern Image" - why not?

Comment: The only way I know of to set the pattern image is when you allocate it. I've already tried every way that I could think of. Perhaps you know a way?

Comment: if you alloc/init them out of the loop **once,** and put it them in the array t that time, then you'll be able to access them at any time by sending `objectAtIndex:` to the array. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I did, it shot back an array error stating that the array couldn't be nil. I investigated, and figured out that the only explanation was that initializing the `UIColor` outside of the for statement was causing it not to be set, which ultimately caused the `addObject:` statement to just be adding NULL objects.

Comment: Please post some code, it's really hard to follow what you're talking about.

Comment: you fail to understand how code sequences are executed. What you wrote makes no sense.

Comment: I know it doesn't, that's why I asked the question in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more explicit explanation of H2CO3's comments:

Define some class properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* colors;
@property (nonatomic, assign) currentColorIndex;
```

Then have a single color initialization routine:

```
- (void)calledDuringInit
{
    self.colors = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i=1; i<=34; i++) 
    {
        NSString *strImgName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"layer%d.png", i];
        UIColor *image = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:strImgName]];
        if (image)
        {
             [self.colors addObject:image];
        }
    }
}
```

At this point the doBackgroundColorAnimation has no need to keep creating the color array:

```
- (void)doBackgroundColorAnimation
{
     if (self.currentColorCount >= [self.colors count]) 
     {
         self.currentColorCount = 1;
     }

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05f
     animations:^{
         self.animationView.backgroundColor = [self.colors objectAtIndex:self.currentColorCount];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         ++self.currentColorCount;
         [self doBackgroundColorAnimation];
     }];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue. This still allocates `UIColor` within the for statement. So when I profile the app, this function takes up nearly all of the CPU.

Comment: This moves the `for` statement out of the `doBackgroundColorAnimation` call though, so you call it 34 times total as opposed to 34 times for every animation cycle.

Comment: Ah, okay I see what you're saying. This helps a lot, but `-(void)calledDuringInit` is still using about 27-30% of the CPU. Anyway I could optimize it more?